# is it possible to change JS variable value from browser console?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

If I have in main.js's file, global variable `a = 5;` and I'm sending this variable with AJAX to PHP, is it possible to change this variable from the console or somehow from the outside and have AJAX send wrong parameter?

Here is an example:

```
var init = {
    id: null,
    setId: function(i){
        this.id = i;
        alert(this.id);
    },
    callAjax: function(){
        alert(this.id);
    }
};
```

If I have this, is it still possible to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is accessible from console (since you are stating that its a global variable), it is possible to modify it from console, just by writing `a=1` or anything.

Answer (score 0):

If this variable is global than it is possible.

To prevent it you must use [closures](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open the browser's console (For Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on PC, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on Mac) and switch to the 'Console' tab. Then just edit the global variable by setting `a=<whatever you want>`.

Because it is in the global scope, you will be able to change it before the AJAX request.